# Use Xcode Auto Layout for different image sizes on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout, size-classes

With Auto Layout for iPhones in Portrait, I don't want the exact same size UIImageViews for game characters on iPhone 6+ as in iPhone 4S. The 4S characters need to be smaller or else they'll look too big. Using Auto Layout how do I change image sizes between iPhones because they seem like they all change to be the same sizes regardless of constraints.

Comment: Sounds like you're setting height and/or width constants. Set the height and/or width relative to the size of the view.

Comment: I'm new to auto layout, how do I set relative to size of view? I don't see that option?

Comment: Are you currently setting auto layout in the Interface Builder? It would be helpful if you could post a link to your project or a screen cap of your auto layout settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that they would be smaller because when you add images, you add 3 sizes of the image: @1x, @2x, and @3x. These images make the image universal for all Apple devices. Try them out in your simulator.